# Using \RequirePackage with parameters

Tags: preamble, parameters

I want to outsource my preamble to a different file. So far I'm doing it with `\RequirePackage`. This ends up looking like this:

```
\RequirePackage{templates}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

My templates file contains everything else and can be an abitrary preamble. Now I want to use a parameter (string) for `\RequirePackage` which I can use in the template file. Normally I would do it like this: `\RequirePackage[Parameter]` and then use it with #1.  This does not work and I couldn't find a website or post that has an answer. Can you help me?

Comment: You can't load files with `#1` being the options (you could, but not with `\RequirePackage`).  With `\RequirePackage` you have to use the `\DeclareOption` machinery from LaTeX or something similar

Comment: Is there a different way I can do it? Maybe \usepackage? I only now these two to outsource preambles. Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: it would be more standard to use usepackage rather than RequirePackage (the commands are identical in behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is basic package writing.  You cannot (not with `\usepackage` at least) refer to options with `#1` and `#2`, you have to use LaTeX's option machinery.  Here's an example to get you started (I wrapped the example package in the `filecontents` environment to keep the example self-contained):

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{templates.sty}
% Declare the conditional and the option
\newif\ifParameter
\DeclareOption{Parameter}{\Parametertrue}

% Process the options
\ProcessOptions

% Do something with the processed conditional
\ifParameter
  \newcommand\somecommand{With option Parameter}
\else
  \newcommand\somecommand{Without option Parameter}
\fi
\end{filecontents}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Parameter]{templates}
\begin{document}
\somecommand
\end{document}
```

The example above prints `With option Parameter`.

---

The first two lines create a conditional `\ifParameter` (which is false by default) and the `\DeclareOption` line creates an option called `Parameter` which sets the `\ifParameter` conditional to true (by using `\Parametertrue`):

```latex
\newif\ifParameter
\DeclareOption{Parameter}{\Parametertrue}
```

Then you use `\ProcessOptions` to process the options given to the package against the ones declared in the package code, and finally you use `\ifParameter .. \else .. \fi` to execute some code conditionally.

---

The syntax of `\DeclareOption` is:

```latex
\DeclareOption{<option>}{<code>}
```

where `<option>` is the option name and `<code>` is whatever code you want executed when that option is given to the package.  Additionally you may use

```latex
\DeclareOption*{<default code>}
```

then the `<default code>` will be used for any option that was not explicitly declared (in `<default code>`, the option used is stored in `\CurrentOption`).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I just needed a bit to understand it :D